# add a button to export a sharepoint list

Tags: list, web-part, sharepoint-online

I want to add a button in a webpart.(i won't use the export boutton in the ribbon)  when I click to the button I want to export my sharepoint list to a excel file.

i used this code 
[image]
but when i save the code a message appear
[image]
the boutton doesn't work and whene i review the code 
[image]